# saving api results to database

Tags: php, api

i am really new to php, so i apologise in advance.
basically i gave created a site for our business for checking technical information about apple products, i am using api that that takes serial number and display results about specific device, for each search we get charged so i want to save search result that gets displayed under tab "recent searches" is there any simple code that i can use?
sample search result of api is as follow:

Cxxxxxxxxxx

Model: Mac mini (M1, 2020)

Serial Number: Cxxxxxxxxxx

Activation Status: ACTIVATED

Warranty Status: Apple Limited Warranty

Coverage Start Date: 16 Jan 2021

Estimated Purchase Date: 16 Jan 2021

Telephone Technical Support: EXPIRED

Repairs and Service Coverage: ACTIVE

Repairs and Service Expiration Date: 15 Jan 2022

Repairs and Service Expires In: 127 days

AppleCare Eligible: NO

Valid Purchase Date: YES

Registered Device: YES

Replaced by Apple: NO

Loaner Device: NO

Comment: You have to use quite a bit. Depends on what you mean by "simple code".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PHP function `json_decode` to convert the JSON data into an associative array. hoping that the data is in fact in JSON and save the array data to the database using some loop and markers.

```
<?php

    $response = "the response from apple";
    $array = json_decode($response);

    // perform whatever functions u want on array 

    
?>
```